# Is there a difference in meaning between "set theoretic difference" and "set difference"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a difference in meaning between "set theoretic difference" and "set difference" for$\ A \backslash B$ in set theory?

- Is the former simply the formal name of the latter, or is there a difference in meaning?
- If there is no difference in meaning, am I OK to use the simpler latter term in place of the longer former term, or is the latter too vague a name for$\ A \backslash B$ in formal proofs?

Comment: There is no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is usually no difference. However a teacher, article or book could define these as different terms, but in such case it would be very important to make this crystal clear (and it still seems like bad manners).

The difference between a formal and an informal proof is the amount of details you use, not how fancy terms you use. For instance the formal term for $a+b$ is saying that we use addition on $a$ and $b$, the less formal is to say that we add $a$ and $b$ and the even less formal is to just say that we plus $a$ and $b$ together. All three are however fine to use in a formal proof and using "plus $a$ and $b$ together" does not make the proof worse, even though the language get less fancy. At time it might even be better to use a less formal language in order to make the proof more readable.

Comment: Really was very useful, @Ove. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The set theoritic difference could be A - B = { x : x in A, x not in B }.
The set difference could be A - B = { a - b : a in A, b in B }.

Comment: You would never notate the latter as $A\setminus B$, though.